# Bounded linear integral operator and its norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $$ Tx(t) = \int_{0}^{1}K(t,s)x(s) ds, \quad x\in C[0, 1],  $$ be an operator, where $K(\cdot,\cdot) $ is a continuous function on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Prove that $T \in \mathcal{L}(C[0,1])$ (bounded linear) and calculate the norm of T.

I would like to ask you for some help as I have no idea how I should approach the problem, the operator topics seem somewhat abstract to me.

(There is no norm candidate provided as opposed to other problems you may find, I would like to know how to figure out one, and as far as the first part of the question goes, does it suffice to show either continuity or boundedness? Which one is easier, intuitive? I would appreciate some explanation.)

Comment: Here is a norm candidate: $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\left|\int_0^1K(t,s)\,ds\right|$.